# Why java calculate dividing a decimal by int like this?

Tags: java

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(0.9/3);
    System.out.println(0.6/3);
  }

  console result (complie with 1.8.0_45)
  0.3
  0.19999999999999998
```

Why I got `0.19999999999999998` instead of `0.2` like first statement `0.3`? This question seems like ridiculous but I really want to know the reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683)

Comment: A quite long explanation can be found here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: The answer is that `0.9` and `0.6` cannot be represented exactly so when you do a calculation on it, sometimes it can hide this representation error and sometimes it cannot.